# Tesseract work fine except on one device give me the Specified module not be found with windows server 2012 r2

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I developed OCR program in java based on tesseract 4.2 and it’s always works for me 
But the last customer witch have windows server 2012 give the exception at the picture below 
And i add microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable 
I tried to get the same windows version and install it On my device and its work 
I am about loss my mind why does this happen

Comment: I couldn’t upload the picture the exception is 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find the correct answer , the problem was the **CPU** of this server doesn't support the **AVX** .
the **solution** is to change the **Tesseract 4.5** that will work on all CPU's
:)